# Using Wordpress's JSON API with W3 Total Cache

Tags: json, string, wordpress

Using the excellent Wordpress plugin, JSON API, I've created an application that retrieves fresh data by visiting a URL along the following lines, doing a Unix curl dump.

http://www.website.net/?json=get_recent_posts&post_type=tree&count=200

The problem is this: Because the site delivers cache versions using W3 Total Cache, the stuff that gets curled is inconsistent. Sometimes I get the JSON that I need. Other times I just get a cache showing me "website.net"'s front page, without the effects of the query string.

I'm hoping to do one of two things:

1) Find a way for my request to bypass w3 Total Cache. But how? Is there something I can put into the query string that will tell Wordpress to give me a fresh page read and not a cache?

If that can't work,

2) Get the plugin data through PHP rather than through the RESTful Web request. But I only know how to use JSON API for Web URL calls and not for using the JSON data internally.

Any help much appreciated. I also thought that maybe W3TC's function to cache query string results might work, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using page cache using disk enhanced in w3tc settings, the URL with query strings will not cached. I think this solves your problem.